# Creating tables in Sage Math Cloud

Tags: sage

I am having an issue creating tables in sage math cloud. It seems that running the table or html.table commands is running differently in sage cloud than in sage, at least as far as I can tell.

In sage (non-cloud), I can run:

```
rows = [[100,2,3], [4,5,60]]
table(rows)
```

fine. It outputs tex code if the "typeset" checkbox is selected, and a table if "typeset" is not selected.

Running

```
rows = [[100,2,3], [4,5,60]]
html.table(rows)
```

Gives a nice looking html table regardless of the typeset button. If I try it in sage cloud, with `typeset_mode(True)`, `table(rows)` gives an

> Unknown environment 'tabular'

error, and `html.tables(rows)` gives an error. Running it with `typeset_mode(False)` gives a good table for `table(rows)`, and an error for `html.table(rows)`. Hopefully I'm missing something obvious - but does anyone have any ideas for getting the tables working in Sage Cloud, ideally keeping `typeset_mode(True)`?

Comment: Correct, there are slight differences between these and you just found one of them.  This is due to the fact that some of these "print" rather than "return" the table in question.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to get a table in sage cloud without having to turn typeset mode off and then on again? Or is that the only option?

Comment: Evidently, MathJax doesn't support the tabular environment: https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-docs/wiki/LaTeX-Tabular-environment

Comment: Ah - thanks @WilliamStein. Bummer.